# TinyMCE change the color of panel and buttons

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Is it possible to change the back ground color of TinyMCE (I am not talking about editor). I am talking about this: 
[image]

**Do I need to overwrite the css from TinyMCE i.e. 'skin.min.css'**? Or there is some other way as well.

That's how I am using TinyMCE right now:

```
 tinymce.init({
            theme: "modern",
            selector: "#contentpage_0_content_0_txtAreaDetails",
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
            ],
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
            editor_css: "/css/TinyMCE/mycontent.css",           
            paste_data_images: true,
            content_css: "/css/TinyMCE/mycontent.css",
            width: 665,
            height: 330


        }); // Tinymce END
```

I also tried to add

```
.mce-panel {
    background-color: red; // just an example
}
```

in `mycontent.css` but it now working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to overwrite `skin.min.css`.
You could optionaly create your own theme (just copy the default theme and apply your changes).

Comment: but still I need to name the file as skin.min.css ? right OR Can you in few words write How Can I create my own theme ?

Comment: Yes, skin.min.css is the name of the css file that gets applied. I have to correct myself, you don't need a new theme, you need a new skin. Just create a new folder named as whatever you like. Copy the contents of the default skin 'lightgray' to this folder and modify it as you like. Set your tinymce params so that the new skin gets applied.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this in your css file:

```
.tox.tox-tinymce * {background: red;}
```

Note: change red to any color you want, obviously.